# How to keep progress bar state while scrolling in listview

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, simplecursoradapter

I have a horizontal progressbar in a each listview row. 
While i select a row and upload, i am scrolling down and when i come back to the row that i was uploding, the progressbar is gone(it is not saving the state when it goes off screen).
I am using SimpleCursorAdapter and sqlite.
I have seen this working, like the android market app, and they do it well. 
Any help? I have been on this for days.

Comment: The problem is in your getView() method

Comment: i am also using bindview. i will post my code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Rect bounds = progressBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();

    ... do your work here

    //reset the bounds before return the view
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);

    return view;
}
```